# Is there a Julia alternative to R predict() method for the MixedModels package?

Tags: r, julia, mixed-models

I have created a linear mixed model in Julia 1.0.4 using the MixedModels and StatsModels packages because lme4 in R does not seem to run on my dataset. Now that I have the model, however, I have not been able to find a way to apply it to test data so I can gauge the model's accuracy. Is there a Julia alternative to the R predict() method that allows new data? I have tried using the Julia predict() method but it only works to predict the same data I created the model with.

I created the model just like this example:

```
mm1 = fit(LinearMixedModel, @formula(Y ~ 1 + (1 | G)), dyestuff)
```

but there does not seem to be a method that would allow something like

```
predict(mm1, test_data)
```

to work in Julia. I have also tried using RCall to send the mm1 variable over to R and use the predict() method that way, but it does not seem like @rput can work with that kind of variable. Thanks!

Comment: For a mixed model, predicting on a new dataset essentially means setting all the random effects to zero. So in your case, you're just predicting the overall (training) mean.

Comment: I probably should have made it more clear in my question, but I am asking about predicting on a test set made up of the same type of data so the random effects would still apply.